# How to get the properties dialog working for color resources in XAML with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, color-picker

I have some color resources

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="basicTextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" >
    <Style.Resources>
        <!--Control colors.-->
        <Color x:Key="WindowColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorLight">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorDark">#FF7381F9</Color>

        <Color x:Key="DisabledControlLightColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DisabledControlDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DisabledForegroundColor">#FF888888</Color>
```

and when I click on the Color node in the XAML I would expect to see in the Properties dialog the color picker so I can decipher those pesky hex color codes. But all I see is

[image]

Is this a feature or a bug of VS?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a perfect solution but the VS2012 plugin `XamlColorPreview` gives an indicator of the hex color underneath like so

[image]